# Solving Matlab ODE equation using python library Scipy in MatLab API

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, matlab-engine

I am trying to solve a stiff ODE system with other methods rather than Rosenbrock as ode23s from Matlab. I would like to use scipy library with various methods such as LSODA or Sundials.

A matlab ODE complex function defined as;

```
function [dpdt]=damper_rebo(t,P,amp,freq,pars)
.....
```

with amp, frequency constants and pars a cell of parameters with constants parameters.
It works fine with;

```
tic
[tsol,ysol]=ode23s(@(t,P) damper_rebo(t,P,amp,freq,pars),[0 0.5/freq],P_0,options);
toc
```

I am trying to compare with other methods to solve ODE with stiff equations like LSODA and BDF.
I loaded the python environment and installed all the path requirements, then I tried this:

```
py.importlib.import_module("scipy")

%--Call out the constant parameters from the function--%%

pars=params7();
pyrun("from scipy.integrate import LSODA")
%-----------------------------------------%

%---Excitation Signal Properties of the Damper---%
amp=25.25e-3;                            % Modal excitational amplitudes (m)
v_n=0.151;
freq=v_n/2/pi/amp;                               % Modal frequency (Hz)
%-------------------------------------%

%--Initial Pressure conditions--%
Pg_0=pars{68};
P_0=[0.01,0.001,1e5,2e5,Pg_0];           % At equilibrium three chambers at the same pressure
%-------------------------------%

% %-------------------------------%
%--Atmospheric Surrounding Temp and Pressure--%
T_atm=15;                                        % Fluid Initial Properties by the supplier
p_atm=101325;
%---------------------------------------------%
Tspan = py.list([0.0, 0.5/freq]);

pyfun = py.str('lambda t,P: damper_rebo(t,P,amp,freq,pars)');
or
pyfun = py.function_handle(@(t,P) damper_rebo(t,P,amp,freq,pars));

sol=py.scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(pyfun,Tspan, py.numpy.array(P_0),pyargs(method="BDF", rtol=0.00001, atol=1e-06));
```

The first `pyfun`option brings an error that `Python Error: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`
The second option brings an error too with `Unable to resolve the name 'py.function_handle'.`

1. How can I pass the Matlab ODE function to a callable python function?
2. How can I pass the extra arguments in a python manner?